# Android Amazon S3 Uploading Crash

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to figure out what is the cause of this crash when uploading on Amazon S3 bucket.

Log is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService$NetworkInfoReceiver.isNetworkConnected()' on a null object reference
   at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService.execCommand(TransferService.java:287)
   at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(TransferService.java:224)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Is there is something wrong on my code?

```
public AmazonTransferUtility uploadFileToAmazonS3(String data, Date date){

    generateTextFileFromString(data, date);

    File jsonFile = new File(getDataPath(), textName);

    TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
            textBucketName,
            mUUID + File.separator + date.getTime() + textName ,
            jsonFile
    );
    mListener.onAsyncStart();

    observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            try {
                if (state.toString().equals("COMPLETED")) {
                    deleteFile(textName);
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
                        result.put("result", state.toString());
                        mListener.onAsyncSuccess(result);
                    }
                }
                else if (state.toString().equals("FAILED") ||
                        state.toString().equals("UNKNOWN")
                        ){
                    mListener.onAsyncFail(id, state.toString());
                }
                else{
                    Log.i(TAG, "S3 TransferState :" + state.toString());
                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                 Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            if (bytesCurrent == bytesTotal){
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed");
            }
            else{
               Log.i(TAG, "Current bytes: " + bytesCurrent + " Of bytesTotal : " + bytesTotal);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            mListener.onAsyncFail(id,ex.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return this;
}
```

And if ever how can I catch this error so that my app stop crashing and just cancel my uploading task.

BTW.

That crash is intermittent and ratio is 1 out of 5 successful sync

Comment: "That crash is intermittent and ratio is 1 out of 5 successful sync" means it sometime works?

Comment: @LazarK yes out of 5 attempts it will only crash once.

Comment: what version of the AWS SDK are you using?

Comment: compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'

    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'

    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'

    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'

Comment: that doesn't show what version you are using, just the range. I'm guessing 2.2.14 (head) based on that, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be something you are doing, it's inside the AWS SDK code. The implication of that NPE is a flaky network. [It's been reported to Amazon on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/117) (and [confirmed in another ticket](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/118)) and it appears rolling back one version in the SDK (v2.2.13) **may** help.

That also [makes sense given the changes made in 2.2.14, which are related to S3 transfer and the network](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#release-2214-03312016).

I'd suggest following those tickets (please don't `+1`). It's reasonable to expect they will fix it within a week.

Comment: I regret to inform that setting version to 2.2.13 does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround until the bug is fixed, just fire this up in your application's `onCreate`, or well before any upload activity starts:

```
/**
 * work around for a bug:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587511/android-amazon-s3-uploading-crash
 */
public static void startupTranferServiceEarlyToAvoidBugs(Context context) {
    final TransferUtility tu = new TransferUtility(
            new AmazonS3Client((AWSCredentials)null),
            context);
    tu.cancel(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1);
}
```

essentially what this does is tell the `TransferService` to start up and initialize it's member variables so that it doesn't enter the condition where it tries to service commands before it's ready to.